# How to add a watchOS Swift target to an iOS app written in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, react-native

I am trying to add a basic `watchOS` target to the "Hello World" React Native iOS app. It seems like the React Native `iOS` App is written in Objective-C, but I want to use Swift in my `watchOS` app. If I select Objective-C when adding the `watchOS` target, everything works. But if I select Swift using the `watchOS` target, I get the following error in my WatchApp Extension:

```
Command Compile SwiftSources failed with nonzero exit code
```

Is there a way to add a Swift `watchOS` target to a React Native `iOS` app, or any other app written in Objective-C?

Comment: Read the full build log , there will be more information there as to why the compile failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by changing the **Library Search Paths** in the Swift target's build settings.

In your project select the Build Settings Menu, and find the **Library Search Paths** setting. (You need to make sure the "All" filter is selected or you will not see this setting). In it's value you'll see two links, use the first one only...  Set the value ov **Library Search Paths** to: `"$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift/$(PLATFORM_NAME)"`

This worked for me